# How to prove the inequality involving the Taylor series

Tags: calculus, logarithms, taylor-expansion

Given $\log((1+x)/(1-x)) = 2x + 2x^3/3 +2x^5/5 \cdots$, how do I prove that

$$\log{\frac{1+x}{1-x}} < 2x + \frac{2x^3}{3(1-x^2)}\qquad x\in (0,1)$$

How could it be that an infinite positive sum of is less than sum of it's finite terms? So the given proof must be False.

Comment: What are you talking about?  Given a strictly positive sequence $a_n$ of course $\sum\limits_{n=1}^N a_n < \lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N a_n$... obviously... but what does that have to do with what you have written?  Check for typos and check specifically what it was you were asked to prove.  In particular, that $(1-x^2)$ that appears... was that in the denominator of that term?  Doesn't that make the second expression sufficiently different than the first such that it can no longer be called a partial sum of the first?

Comment: Yes it is in denominator

Comment: Hint: There's a useful sum expansion of $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$.

Comment: @aschepler Sir try the Taylor series of $1/(1-x^2)$ about 0 but l can't come up with conclusion . Please  explain more